# Action listeners not firing

Tags: actionlistener, codenameone

I've been developing with codenameone for over a year, and I never ran into this problem before, I feel like I'm losing my mind. I just redesigned one part of an app I'm working on, and now the `ActionListener`s aren't firing.  I'm attaching them to a `Button` and a `SpanButton` in the code:

```
        ActionListener goToDoc = new ActionListener() {
            String mDocId = docId;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                mStateMachine.currentExpertId = mDocId;
                mStateMachine.showForm("DoctorDetails", null);
            }
        };
        name.addActionListener(goToDoc);
        Util.downloadImageToStorage(mStateMachine.URL_PREFIX+"images/doctors/"+(String)value.get("doc_pic"), 
                "doc_post_pic_"+(String)value.get("doc_id")+".png", new Callback<Image>() {
            @Override
            public void onSucess(Image img) {
                pic.setIcon(img.scaledWidth(mStateMachine.getProportionalWidth(.23)));
                StateMachine.applyGreenBorder(pic);
                pic.addActionListener(goToDoc);
                pic.getParent().revalidate();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Object sender, Throwable err, int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
                System.out.println("Unable to download expert profile picture");
            }
        });
```

When I debug the code, the components do show that the `ActionListener` is attached, but the `actionPerformed` method is never reached, no matter how many times I click on the buttons. I experience this problem both on the simulator and on an Android device. I have yet to test on an iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the click event wasn't firing was because the Components weren't enabled, possibly a bug in the BUI Builder.  After checking off the 'Enabled' and 'Focusable' checkboxes in the GUI Builder, and seeing they were unchecked every time I went back to that form, I just used `component.setFocusable(true)` and `component.setEnabled(true)` in the code, and it worked fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set a parent to be a lead component or focusable?

Comment: No, the parent is a plain BoxLayout Y container.  This answer should have been a comment, btw.

Comment: I suggest overriding the forms pointer released event and after calling super checking the focused component.

Comment: How do I do that with a GUI builder form?

Comment: You can use a pointer listener on the form and in the callback event inspect the parent form object or just call the get focused component method.

Comment: I did as you suggested, and the focused component is the one being pressed, but its own `ActionListener` is still not being fired.  Another thing I noticed is that in the GUI builder the 'enabled' and 'focused' checkboxes for this component always automatically uncheck themselves, no matter how many times I check them and save, every time I return to that form, they're unchecked.

Comment: Focused or focusable? Those are very different things! If the component isn't enabled then you can't press it and can't get an action event which would explain exactly why this isn't working. What's the component and how did you add it? Did you set other values within the properties that would trigger that?

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right, I'm referring to the 'focusable' attribute checkbox in the GUI Builder.  For only two particular components, a Button and a SpanButton, the 'focusable' and 'enabled' attributes don't persist.

Comment: If a component isn't enabled it can't get an action event. I'm guessing you are referring to a button within the span button or some other lead hierarchy. I'm not sure why this won't be enabled but that's pretty clearly the problem...